Auth Issue with UKG pro workforce management APIs
I have been trying to use the apis on the Pro workforce management side and i keep getting the same error.
{
"errorCode": "GTW-ERROR-005",
"message": "UnAuthorized. Authentication Failed."
}
I have gone back to the tutorials to get why and it still not working. i have tried contacting UKG support but they are very slow and not helpful. I know i am getting the AccessToken correctly and setting up both of the basic calls but i am just stumped why i am getting a unauth error.
this is the format of the the response i get when i get the auth token
{
"access_token": "token",
"scope": "",
"id_token": "stuff",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 1799
}
